# Angular's router is not working when preventing default event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, passport.js, angular-fullstack

I'm using Angular-Fullstack generator from Yeoman package, including Passport.js (FB, G+, Twitter)

I've got into a problem where in my main event `$stageChangeStart` on application's run, the expression of `$location.path('/login');` does nothing. Even though it alerts before and after the expression call, which means the code gets there safely, and there's no `console.log` errors.

It happened after I've added `event.preventDefault();` before location expression:

```
.run(function ($rootScope, $location, Auth) {
// Redirect to login if route requires auth and you're not logged in
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, next) {
  Auth.isLoggedInAsync(function(loggedIn) {
    if (next.authenticate && !loggedIn) {
      event.preventDefault();
      // alerts here
      $location.path('/login');
      // alerts here as well
    }
  });
});
```

The reason for adding that preventDefault was to try and solve other problem.

Via `NODE_ENV=development` the redirect after successful login to /home works perfectly, though when I build the project with Grunt and run it on a remote server, that particular redirect doesn't work anymore, even though I can see the specific call to `$location.path('/home')` in my uglified code.

I even put a check in `main.controller.js` to ensure it redirects to /home if user is authenticated:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('fckyeah')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http, Auth, socket, $location) {
    if (Auth.isLoggedIn()) {
      $location.path('/home');
    }
  });
```

After successful login, the redirect that happens is in my LoginCtrl:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('fckyeah')
.controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, Auth, $location, $window) {
  $scope.user = {};
  $scope.errors = {};

  $scope.login = function(form) {
    $scope.submitted = true;

  if(form.$valid) {
    Auth.login({
      email: $scope.user.email,
      password: $scope.user.password
    })
    .then( function() {
      // Logged in, redirect to home
      $location.path('/home');
    })
    .catch( function(err) {
      $scope.errors.other = err.message;
    });
  }
};

$scope.loginOauth = function(provider) {
  $window.location.href = '/auth/' + provider;
};
});
```

So when running it with `NODE_ENV=production`, what happens is, it redirects to /#_# or something like that and then to "/", a "main" route, not "home" as expected, after successful login, and only manual attempt to go to /home - works.

I'm trying to understand why I have difference in behaviour between environments and why preventDefault stops the ngRouter completely from operating.
It makes it dangerous to rely on your development environment where it fails to deliver the same functionality on production.

Appreciate any advice on this case.

Comment: as far as i noticed, sometimes you need to wrap those location changes via setTimeout or $timeout with ui-router. also looks like you mixing concept of ui-router and ngRouter, they are different thing.

Answer (score 0):

At first, as you are using `ui-router`

instead of `$location.path('/login');`, you must use

```
$state.go("statename")
```

As it's very specific to production environment, My best guess is the dependencies are not injected properly. So when you're uglifying your code, make sure you use the array notation for binding the function with controller.

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, Auth, $location, $window) {
```

must be like

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', ["$scope", "Auth", "$location", "$window", function ($scope, Auth, $location, $window) {
// your code here
}]);
```

This is to make sure that all the dependencies are injected properly.

Comment: Do I need to inject ``$state`` before using it or it's globally available when including ``ui.router`` on module declaration?

Comment: Yes, you need to inject `$state` n your `run` method

Comment: Did that, changed all ``$location`` to ``$state``, same problem, but with introduction to ``$state``, I don't have a URL now, it shows me "home" state on a "/" URL. Is there a codepen or something that have Angular-Fullstack so I can introduce the issue?

Comment: you can setup that in plnkr.co / jsbin.com. I will check and let you know

Comment: Actually, since the problem occurs after Grunt build, and plnkr or jsbin doesn't have support for deploying YeoMan generators and all NPM dependencies, I'm not sure I will be able to create accurate example.